# Can anyone outline the steps for constructing general colimits?

Tags: category-theory

Specifically, in a cocomplete category how can one construct general colimits via other colimits such as initial objects,Coproducts and Coequalizers? (I would prefer not very heavy mathematical notation if possible....)

Comment: Did you consult any standard text on category theory? any such book will answer your question in detail.

Comment: I have but they are difficult to understand. I would just like an outline in words

Comment: You find these outlines everywhere. You should make explicit why these references don't satisfy (because otherwise we don't know what we should explain differently).

Comment: related (but different): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335177/are-projective-limits-always-subobjects-of-a-product-and-dualy-inductive-limits

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach this question is to look at a generic example, like $\Bbb{Set}$.

Perhaps the dual statement is even easier to visualize: so let us try to express any limit by means of products and an equalizer.

If a diagram (i.e. a functor from a small category $\Delta$), $\ D:\Delta\to \Bbb{Set}\ $ is given, its limit in $\Bbb{Set}$ is the subset of the product
$$L:=\left\{(a_x)_{x\in Ob\Delta}\,\mid\, \forall \alpha:x\to y\ \text{ in }\Delta\ \left(a_y=D\alpha(a_x)\right) \right\}\quad
\subseteq\ \prod_{x\in Ob\Delta} D(x)$$
Now, for each arrow $\alpha:u\to v\,$ in $\Delta$, we indicated two functions $\prod_{x\in Ob\Delta}D(x)\to D(v)$ in the defining equation:
$$ f_\alpha:=(a_x)_x\,\mapsto a_v\ \ \text{ and }\ \ 
g_\alpha:=(a_x)_x\,\mapsto D\alpha(a_u)\,.$$
These altogether define two maps between products:
$$ \prod_{x\in Ob\Delta} D(x) \ \underset{g}{\overset{f}\rightrightarrows}\  
\prod_{\matrix{\alpha\in \Delta,\\ \alpha:u\to v}} D(v)\,.$$
 And, the limit subset $L$ can be given as their equalizer.

This idea with the final setup can be fully formalized for the general case (using projections and the product property), and you can verify that the resulting equalizer will indeed satisfy the limit property for the diagram $D$.

By dualizing the general proof, we get the dual statement for colimits. I suggest to write it up as well in $\Bbb{Set}$.

Note also that if $\Delta$ is finite, then all products involved are finite.

Comment: Limits in $\mathbf{Set}$ are generic, thanks to the Yoneda embedding. But I would not say that colimits in $\mathbf{Set}$ are generic...

Comment: Well, yes, that's why I switched to limits. But the dual construction can be performed in $\Bbb{Set}$ as well.

Comment: It's interesting to note that in does not make a difference if we include the identity arrows in the right hand product or exclude them.

Comment: Also, it is enough to define it on a *generating* graph with commutativity conditions (pairs of parallel paths) of the category $\Delta$.