# Are projective limits always subobjects of a product and dualy, inductive limits quotient objects of a coproduct?

Tags: category-theory

This question is motivated by the first few explicit examples I came across, e.g.

[Wikipedia, Inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#Algebraic_objects) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332806/projective-or-inverse-limit-of-c-algebras) or [Wiki, Direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Algebraic_objects)

In order to answer that question, let's start with the following two examples and an attempt to link the pullback and pushforward to the product and coproduct respectively. In the category $ \mathbf{Set} $ with monomorphisms only as arrows, these correspond respectively to the intersection and union:

[image: $X\cap Y$ as Pullback of $\iota_{X/Y}: X/Y\rightarrow Z$ - $X\cup Y$ as pushforward of $p_{X/Y}: X\cap Y\rightarrow X/Y$]

The explicit (and seemingly general) constructed goes like
$$ X\cap Y:= \left\{(x,y)\in X\times Y,\ \iota_X(x) = \iota_Y (y) \right\}$$
where $p_{X/Y}$ are the projections on the first (resp. second) element in the pair $(x,y)$. (This construction actually corresponds to $\Delta(X\cap Y)\subset Z\times Z$ where $\Delta$ is the "diagonal map") and 
$$ X\cup Y:= X\coprod Y \Bigg/\sim$$
where $\sim$ is the finest equivalence relation such that 
$$ u\sim v ,\enspace u,v\in X\coprod Y \quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad u=i_X\circ p_X (x,y),\ v=i_Y\circ p_Y (x,y)\ \text{for some}\ (x,y)\in X\cap Y$$

(The attemp to relate intersection-product and union-coprodut by inserting $Q:= X\times Y$ or $P:= X\coprod Y$ in their respective diagrams fails because these don't make the diagrams commute.)

However, one can insert $C:= X\cap Y,\ f/g = p_X/p_Y$ in the following product diagram and $D:= X\cup Y,\ h/l =i_X/i_Y$ in the coproduct diagram:

[image: Produit Coproduit]

This gives a maps $\Phi : X\cap Y \rightarrow X\times Y$ and $\Psi: X\coprod Y \rightarrow X\cup Y$. The question can now be formulated as: under what condition are $\Psi,\Phi$ respectively monomorphism, epimorphism?

Same question for more general projective limits and inductive limits.

**Remark:** In e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928562/does-the-intersection-of-sets-have-a-categorical-interpretation/928961#928961), people emphasized that the diagrams correspond to the set construction only in $\mathbf{Set}$ with monomorphisms as arrows, not will all arrows, so that $\Psi$ is naturally a monomorphism, i.e. $X\cap Y$ a subobject of $X\times Y$.

Feel free to add the relevant tags.

Comment: Yes. Every limit can be written as an *equalizer* between two *products*, and equalizers are always monomorphisms.

Comment: Oh nice, I've (vaguely) seen that theorem but I did not make the link. As soon as I have time (probably in a long time), I'll develop an answer

Comment: @Berci: This is only true if products exist. A counterexample to your claim is the dual of the category of finite abelian groups.